# I don't think my variables are being passed to jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, tooltipster

I'm trying to change the offset based on the State that is currently being hovered over and pass the two attributes ("data-doff" and "data-yoff") to the tooltipster plugin so that when you hover over a state, the name pops up in the tooltip in the centre of the State, but it's not working.
I had used "alert()" to have it tell me what it found and it can read the attributes, it's just not using them, but I don't understand what I'm doing incorrectly.
Any ideas?

My jQuery script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.showState').hover(function () {

        var xoff = $(this).attr('data-xoff');
        var yoff = $(this).attr('data-yoff');

        $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            animation: 'grow',
            delay: 0,
            theme: '.ads-theme',
            arrow: false,
            offsetX: xoff,
            offsetY: yoff
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Relevant HTML

```
<area shape="poly" alt="California" title="California" coords="111...363" href="usa_py_expander.asp?lang=<%=mapLanguage%>&regionID=126" class="py_display fancybox-iframe tooltip showState" data-width="260" data-height="350" data-xoff="0" data-yoff="-150">
```

Comment: Are you saying `xoff` and `yoff` don't contain what you expect? and you've logged/alerted them to find them empty?

Comment: No, they have the correct numbers, but the tooltip stays in the same position, so I know it's not using them.

Comment: Oh, it's using them, it just probably doesn't know how to handle being initialized more than once. It's probably just returning early and doing nothing since it's been initialized already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, plugins need to be initialized on DOM ready, not when the event that should trigger them occurs. You probably need to do something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.showState').each(function () {
        $this = $(this);

        var xoff = $this.attr('data-xoff');
        var yoff = $this.attr('data-yoff');

        $this.tooltipster({
            animation: 'grow',
            delay: 0,
            theme: '.ads-theme',
            arrow: false,
            offsetX: xoff,
            offsetY: yoff
        });
    });
});
```

It's also preferable to use `data('whatever')` instead of `attr('data-whatever')`.

Comment: It's still not using them yet. Do I need to use parseInt to make sure it knows they are numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice something, it is working now. Thanks VERY much!